# Contacts favorites search bar

Tags: android, view, searchbar

I'd like to replicate the search bar in Contacts app > Favorites > Search (sans icon). Could someone give me a few tips?

A linear layout maybe with some top, left and bottom padding, width is fill_parent, and a weight of 1? With a button next to it with some right padding? How do I make the button look like that? Is there a parameter I can set to get the gradient background of the back? Or do I need to supply an image?

[Screen shot](http://i34.tinypic.com/nltsgx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/search/index.html) and see the implemented code of that app in this [git repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=summary).